# Wordpress, hosting a live project from a local one used on xampp

Tags: wordpress, xampp

What sort of variables do I need to change to host a wordpress project from a local one that was created by a third party on a live domain?

Apart from changing the datbase in wp.config, what do I need?

Thanks

Comment: An Update: The project itself was basically a template that was created. 
The database must only contain user + password to access everything. 
I have created the database on the domain and given a new user password + all privileges. 

Would making amendments to the config.php file let me access the site that is hosted?

Comment: Another update. I have got my hands on the localhost.sql file.
How should one make additions and upload it through the domain host?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're basically changing servers (local to live) and domains (localhost to a new URL).

1. Copy your WordPress files to the new server.
2. Export your database (you can use phpMyAdmin on XAMPP) that you've used for the installation. Do a find and replace for the old domain to the new domain. This will fix image links as well if you have any posts with images.
3. Because you'll have a new database, you'll also need to change wp-config.php to reflect the new credentials for your live database.

Since you're copying over files, your .htaccess will be replicated and you shouldn't need to reset permalinks. Let me know how your move works out and if any issues arise.

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer.

The database wasn't passed on to me, is it an external file that needs to be extracted via xampp so I can import it via the domain cpanel?

Comment: You're using cPanel? Then, there should be an option to create a new MySQL database and a new user with all privileges for that database. That's where you get the new credentials from. Once you create a new database, you can go into your XAMPP database on phpMyAdmin to export the SQL file to, for instance, your desktop, which you can later import back into your new database using phpMyAdmin via cPanel.

Comment: I get the following error message while trying to import the database through xampp in Cpanel

Error
SQL query:
--
-- Database: `wordpress`
--
CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS `wordpress` DEFAULT CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_swedish_ci;
MySQL said: Documentation
#1044 - Access denied for user 'malacore'@'localhost' to database 'wordpress' 

Just to be sure, does the database name that needs to be imported have to be matched with the one created on Cpanel? same with user / password?

Comment: Update: 
Created a new database called malacore_test and user malacore_test.
Changed the localhost.sql file to use the newly created database (to bypass the error). 
The import went successful through xampp manager on cpanel, however the site gives the following error: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '{' in /home/malacore/public_html/annatilburyart.com/wp-content/plugins/register-plus-redux/rpr-login.php on line 1

Comment: So the database is fine and the live domain takes you to the WordPress as it should. Try disabling register-plus-redux to ensure that your WordPress site looks as it should. As for the error, it's a plugin issue. What version of PHP does your server use?

Comment: Im not sure how to disable registerplus-redux without access the site via wordpress. 
The php version is: 5.4.22

Comment: You can just add a '1' to the end of the plugin folder name. WordPress will try looking for the plugin, assume it's gone, and disable it for you. Do you have FTP access or the ability to use cPanel file manager?

Comment: Yes I use filezilla for that. Ok so I changed the folder name for the plugin and every single image / template is not recognized and the text formatting is all messed up. I think that plugin defines the template itself. 
Is there a way to fix the error rather than to bypass it? 
By the way you have been very helpful and patient with a very rookie wordpress user, thank you

Comment: Ok so wordpress is not recognized if the plugin is disabled hence why the formatting is non existent. 
It just looks like a messy html template.

Comment: Is it live right now so I can see it? That plugin doesn't have such a wide impact on the site - only the registration process, I presume. If there are images not loading or CSS files giving 404's, then there are still old links where there should be new links in the database tables. Considering that there's no redirect errors, I assume that the find and replace at least hit the base/site URL, where it counts. WordPress works closely with the database, and plugins usually work relatively with paths, grabbing the theme or home URL and working from there.

Comment: ofcourse the url is www.annatilburyart.com
Im clueless to be honest. I have tried various methods to try and fix the error but it seems like there is nothing wrong with the database.

Comment: There's still a lot of links pointing to localhost (Screenshot: [link](http://i.imgur.com/O2o5Rtq.png)). Try forcing WordPress to acknowledge your new URL (Instructions: [here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_The_Site_URL#Relocate_method))

Comment: Success!!! Adding define('WP_HOME','http://example.com');
define('WP_SITEURL','http://example.com'); Lines within the constructor in the wpconfig.php file did it. 
However some functionality is still broken. 
Now i cannot even connect to the admin panel using the username/password within the wpconfig.php file that i used to establish the connection in the first place. 
[link](http://annatilburyart.com)

Comment: Sorry for the delay! You have one image still pointing to localhost. As for logging into WordPress, the credentials are the user account you created during the installation, not the database. It seems that the other pages of the site are working well.